# String with AM/PM to Date

Tags: java

I am not able to pass the string with AM/PM to timestamp(date).

Here is the piece of code what I am trying.

```
public static Date parseDate() {
    String format = "dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss a";
    String sdate = "07-May-2018 12:00:00 AM";
    Date util_sdate = null;

    try {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
        sdf.setLenient(false);
        util_sdate = sdf.parse(sdate);
    } catch (ParseException pe) {
        pe.printStackTrace();
    }

    return util_sdate;
}
```

And I am getting the following exception.

> java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "07-May-2018 12:00:00 AM"

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have defined wrong format.
Because you are defining your date in AM/PM format, you can't pass hrs as 24 (HH).

```
format = "dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss a"; //small case hh
```

Above is what you should use.